# Pseudo Inverses of covariance matrices that are close to each other

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, numerical-linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

I am trying to understand inverses of covariance matrices that are close to each other.

I start with a positive semidefinite matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}}$, then I take the pseudo-inverse to get covariance matrix $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. Then this is transform into correlation matrix, $$\mathbf{R = D^{-1}\ \Sigma\ D^{-1}} \ \ \text{where}\ \ \mathbf{D} =  \sqrt{\operatorname{diag}(\mathbf{\Sigma})}$$ and then I generate correlated random variables $\mathbf{x}$ which have correlation matrix $\mathbf{R^{'}}$, which is not exact same as $\mathbf{R}$ but is very close. I then convert $\mathbf{R^{'}}$ as above to get $\mathbf{\Sigma^{'}}$ which is close to original $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. I am trying now to invert this $\mathbf{\Sigma^{'}}$ to get the $\mathbf{\Sigma^{'-1}}$ which I would expect is good approximation of $\mathbf{\Sigma}$. However when I actually perform this procedure, I get a $\mathbf{\Sigma^{'}}$ that is indeed close to $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ but the inverse $\mathbf{\Sigma^{'-1}}$ is completely different from $\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}}$. It is not only the non-zero entries that are different, the pattern of zero is also completely different.

I am doing the above to test out part of an algorithm for coursework assignment, but am not able to proceed because $\mathbf{\Sigma^{'-1}}$ is clearly not even close to $\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}}$.

I understand from other questions on this site that it is not guaranteed that matrices close to each other will always produce inverses that is close. In this case is there procedure to invert $\mathbf{\Sigma^{'}}$ which will give a good approximation for $\mathbf{\Sigma^{-1}}$?

Comment: your title is about inverses but your actual post is (mostly?) about pseduo inverses.  Proper inverses are continuous (e.g. continuity of the determinant and Cramer's Rule give this result).  Pseudo inverses aren't in general continuous.  This distinction matters.

Comment: @user8675309 Thank you for pointing out this difference. Yes I use the pseudo inverse. Is it possible to get around the issue that I am raising by using the inverse? For example, by adding a small shift to the psd matrix so that it is not singular and then just using instead the inverse? Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear: Is it correct that you're deliberately starting with a matrix of less than full rank? In what context is all this being done? Why are you starting with such a matrix as proceeding as above?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes I have matrix which is not full rank. The context of this is that the starting matrix $\Sigma^{-1}$ is a laplacian of a graph. I have also try to shift the spectrum with a small value $\epsilon$ to see if this solves the problem but it still does not. Thanks.